Where does this content security policy come from?
Our organization uses Google Suite for Education Standard through our organization's URL. Almost all our users use Chrome and are logged into GSE using an email address ending in @[mycompany].org. My administrator is trying to use the Asana app. However, when they try to log in using Google, after they click the 'log in with Google' button and their email address, gets a 'sad face' screen saying "this content is blocked."
The console shows the following error:
Refused to frame 'https://asana.s3.amazonaws.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' blob: https://www.figma.com https://*.invisionapp.com https://invis.io https://miro.com https://whimsical.com https://www.loom.com https://www.youtube.com https://player.vimeo.com https://fast.wistia.com https://www.canva.com https://xd.adobe.com https://*.looker.com https://lucid.app https://*.okta.com https://*.sharepoint.com https://accounts.google.com https://accounts.google.com/gsi/ https://content.googleapis.com https://www.google.com https://docs.google.com https://fast.wistia.net https://www.dropbox.com https://platform.harvestapp.com https://forms.asana.plus https://forms-server.asana.plus https://local.asana.com https://asana.com https://apisandbox.zuora.com https://test.zuora.com https://www.zuora.com https://www.sandbox.paypal.com https://www.paypal.com https://recordwidget.vimeocdn.com https://api.stripe.com https://hooks.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com https://m.stripe.com https://m.stripe.network https://q.stripe.com https://d3ki9tyy5l5ruj.cloudfront.net https://prod-eu1.app.asana.com https://prod-au1.app.asana.com https://prod-jp1.app.asana.com https://cdn.cookielaw.org https://form.asana.com https://form-beta.asana.com https://resources.asana.com https://ccwizard.vertexsmb.com https://*.qualtrics.com".

Clearly the problem is that the content security policy does not include the domain asana.s3.amazonaws.com. The question is, where is the content security policy coming from?
I assumed it was being injected by Google, for two reasons. First of all, this problem only happens when we try to log in using Google from our domain; if I do it from my personal gmail it works fine. If the problem was in Asana's code it would be happening to everyone and be a much bigger problem for Asana. Second of all, when I look at the content security policy report below it says the referrer is accounts.google.com.
csp-report: {document-uri: "https://app.asana.com/?rr=633787", referrer: "https://accounts.google.com/",…}

However, Google technical support claims they have nothing to do with this CSP. Asana won't even give me the time of day. Is there any way to tell what the actual origin of this CSP is so I can know who to fight with?

Asana app is the reason. Looks like a bug to me, I recommend to report it to Asana and use an alternative login until it's fixed.
